# How are delegates linked to events?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I've read lots of material and examples regarding delegates and events but am really struggling to understand events in C#. I understand that delegates are effectively method pointers, which you can add methods to then execute all together when you call the delegate, assuming it conforms to the input parameters and return type of the delegate.

(I'm very aware that events are explained on stack overflow but not even that helped me understand)

I'll share my code which is working but I don't understand

```
namespace Delegates2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Car mazda = new Car("Mazda");
            Person chris = new Person();
            mazda.Drive += chris.OnPersonDrive;
            mazda.StartJourney();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    public delegate void DriverCarEventHandler(object obj, EventArgs e);
    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public event DriverCarEventHandler Drive;    

        public Car(string name) {
            Name = name;
        }
        public void StartJourney() {
            OnDrive();
        }
        protected virtual void OnDrive() {
            if (Drive != null) {
                Drive(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public void OnPersonDrive(Object source, EventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Driving....");
        } 
    }
}
```

Here are all my confusion points...

- What do 'Object obj' and 'EventArgs e' in the delegate declaration
  represent? For learning is seems these are quite often empty. What might be an example of where these might need to be different?
- When you create an event based on a delegate, does the
  event now store all the pointers to methods or is it still the
  delegate? I've heard terminology used about adding subscribers to an
  event. Are these 'subscribers' just methods in the same way you would
  add methods to delegates?
- Apparently the OnDrive() method is 'raising' the event. Is 'raising' an event the same as executing the
  event? So executing all the subscribers attached to the event?
- Why when your raising an event does it have to conform to the
  delegate    input parameters? (this, EventArgs.Empty). Isn't it the
  subscribers    only that need to match this format?

Comment: "I understand that delegates are effectively method pointers, which you can add methods to then execute all together when you call the delegate" - that's exactly what events are. They are delegates that are exposed from your objects that you can add method pointers to that get executed when the object itself wishes to raise them. The major difference between delegates and events is that events can only be raised (executed) by the class that holds them and delegates can be executed by any code.

Comment: You don't need to add objects and event args in delegates... they are events you make yourself. You can add no paramaters or just a string or something -_-

Comment: @PeterDuniho Point still stands, you can pick your own parameters for a delegate YOU make

Comment: @EpicKip: sorry, I misunderstood your comment and thought you meant you could use a non-delegate type for an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your questions as briefly as possible, to avoid making your question "too broad"…

> •What do 'Object obj' and 'EventArgs e' in the delegate declaration represent? For learning is seems these are quite often empty. What might be an example of where these might need to be different?

`obj` should always be non-null, and should be set to the reference of the object raising the event. `e` should be the instance of the `EventArgs` or derived class, containing information related to the event.

It is important to note that this pattern is *strictly conventional*. I.e. not enforced by anyone, and not required. A C# `event` can use *any* delegate type. The `EventHandler` delegate type is simply the basis for the *standard* way to implement events in .NET.

> •When you create an event based on a delegate, does the event now store all the pointers to methods or is it still the delegate? I've heard terminology used about adding subscribers to an event. Are these 'subscribers' just methods in the same way you would add methods to delegates?

Most events are implemented implicitly by the compiler. But it's important to understand that when you use the `event` keyword, you are declaring both an `add` and a `remove` method for the event. These are analogous to the `get` and `set` methods for a property. The default implementation simply takes the delegate instance passed in and either appends it to or removes it from the existing value for the event's backing field (also implicitly generated for you), for the `add` and `remove` methods respectively.

The default implementation for an event stores this in a single, simple `delegate` type field. There are implementations of events that are more complicated, such as putting the event handler reference in a dictionary, or using weak references.

> •Apparently the OnDrive() method is 'raising' the event. Is 'raising' an event the same as executing the event? So executing all the subscribers attached to the event?

Yes, raising an event is simply a matter of invoking the delegates that were added (subscribed) to the event. The .NET delegate types are all "multi-cast" delegates, so a single delegate instance can represent multiple invocation targets. Invoking the one delegate instance will automatically call *all* of the individual invocation targets.

By convention, a method named `OnXXX()` where `XXX` is the name of some event will always raise that event. But there's no requirement to do so. One obvious exception is when the event field is `null`, i.e. there are no handers subscribed to the event. In that case, obviously the event isn't raised. Another, more specific, real-world example would be various events exposed by the `Control` objects in the Winforms API, which have several exceptions to the rule (for events pertaining to changes in visual state, like the current font, background color, enabled state, etc.), short-cutting the event-raising logic and returning without raising the event if the object or any of its ancestor objects (i.e. parents, grandparents, etc.) are in the process of being disposed.

> •Why when your raising an event does it have to conform to the delegate input parameters? (this, EventArgs.Empty). Isn't it the subscribers only that need to match this format?

To invoke a delegate, the code *must* pass the necessary parameters to it, just as when you call *any* method you are required to pass the necessary parameters to it (even if there are default values, the compiler generates the code necessary to ensure all of the parameter values are provided).

If the invoker of the delegate didn't pass the parameter values, where would the values that are eventually passed to the target method come from?

Comment: Many Thanks Peter. So for the purposes of learning is it fair to think of an event handler as an object that stores a delegate field, and that object has add or remove methods for that and only that delegate? Then when you add a subscriber you are going to the EventHandler -> EventHandler delegate to store the subscriber (as a method). Is `Drive != null` referencing the existence of a delegate linked to an event, or is it referencing the existence of subscribers/methods that are pointed to by the event handler delegate?

Comment: I would suggest adding to the `OnDrive()` answer to say that the `OnDrive()` method has no obligation to actually raise the event - it's up to the its own internal logic as to if the event should be raised or not.

Comment: @Konzy262: I wouldn't think of an `event` as an object, as that could be confusing in the context where you have actual "objects" in the language. I.e. the `event` is a lot more like a property, field, or method than a `class` or `struct` (i.e. things which are truly "objects"). But yes, otherwise you are right...the `event` maintains, however is desired, a way to track delegates that are added/removed to/from the event.

Comment: @Konzy262: The expression `Drive != null` is an artifact of the auto implementation of the event the compiler provides. Using the auto implementation, the compiler actually generates _two_ class members with the same name, e.g. `Drive`. For code _outside_ the class, that name refers to the `event` member of the class. But for code _inside_ the class, the name refers to the _backing field_ for the event, i.e. the thing that the event's `add` and `remove` methods use to track subscribers. Being a delegate type, it can be compared to `null`, and invoked using normal delegate-invocation syntax.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - There are circumstances where events are silenced - for one example I just checked the source for `System.Windows.Forms.Control.cs` and the `OnBackColorChanged` method has a guard at the beginning that can prevent the event firing. I'm sure there are plenty of others. So just by calling an `On*` method it doesn't mean the event will fire.

Comment: @Enigmativity: okay, I've added some discussion of that aspect of the `OnXXX()` method. Let me know if you think it warrants further improvement.